# How do I control GPIO pins from anywhere in the world?

Tags: gpio, web

I need to be able to control something with a GPIO pin that is connected to a relay or whatever. How do I do this?

I want to be able to control this from anywhere in my state. Basically through work spots or with a text or an email. Preferably all 3. Or whichever is best and easiest.

Comment: I think that question is too broad. This is not a tutorial site where you can ask how to do questions. Show us your efforts what you have done so far to tackle this issue. The more efforts you show in question, the more ppl will try to solve your issue. In a broad way, it can be done easily via web server method where you have hosted a web page on rpi, which is connected to relay or something via GPIO or indirectly. For text method to work, you might need a GSM module. Hope it helps.

Comment: I think the question is high level, and appropriately answered at high level. From the gist, I doubt OP is looking to build a system from the ground up ("easiest", "gamer").

Comment: Realistically the key component of a solution is going to be an intermediate server on the publicly routable Internet, which proxies information between your controller and the pi sitting behind whatever firewalls and/or NAT is imposed on most Internet connections available/affordable to ordinary end users today.  Fortunately, you don't have to build that yourself on an aws instance - there are a variety of such service offerings available due to the growing general interest in IoT.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [WebIOPi](http://webiopi.trouch.com/) which has a web-interface which should work in any browser and therefore doesn't need installation on controlling devices.
It has a Python client library , so you can build your own solution if the default web-interface does not meet your needs.